# After "a{display text}", then pasting the url, how can I get the cursor to go after the close </a>? Like $0 in a Sublime autocomplete

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet

I'm using Emmet in Sublime Text 3.

After executing `a{display text}`, you get

```
<a href="__CURSOR__">display text</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the cursor to jump to after the close `</a>`, after I've pasted in the url. I'm trying to simulate Sublime's autocomplete `$0` behavior, like

```
<a href="$1">display text</a>$0
```

I am looking through snippets.json, but I'm not getting it. The only "a" entry is in the "abbreviations" object, and contains only the open tag:

```
"a": "<a href=\"\">",
```

I've not edited any Emmet tags before, and I thought this might be a good first one to try.

Any ideas on how this might be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in Emmet setting that does this for all tags:

This is in `C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Emmet\Emmet.sublime-settings`

```
// If set to `true`, Emmet will automatically insert final tabstop
// at the end of expanded abbreviation
"insert_final_tabstop": false
```

I duplicated it to `C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Emmet.sublime-settings`

and changed it to `true`. It does exactly as I want. Well, it still goes to the display text, even if there already is display text. Then it goes to the end. But close enough!